# Annotation based Delayer

Tags: spring-integration

I am working on my first spring-integration use case. I would like to do everything in pure Spring Java Config (no XML configuration and DSL, only annotations). So far everything was OK despite lack of documentation and examples.

But now I have problem with delayer. There is no obvious annotation and there is nothing in documentation regarding configuring delayer in DSL or annotation. Is delayer supported only in XML configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java DSL on the matter should be obvious:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow delayFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("delayInput")
            .delay("delayer", d -> d
                    .delayExpression("200")
                    .advice(this.delayedAdvice)
                    .messageStore(messageStore()))
            .get();
}
```

For the raw Java & Annotation configuration pay attention to  [Programming Tips and Tricks](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips).

The main point for you is this:

> If you are familiar with Spring Integration XML configuration already, starting with version 4.3, we provide in the XSD elements definitions the description with the pointer which target classes are used to produce beans for the adapter or gateway.

So, going to the `<delayer>` XSD we see:

```
<xsd:documentation>
            Defines a Consumer Endpoint for the 'org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler'
            that passes a Message to the output-channel after a delay.
```

Having a sample above about `sendChatMessageHandler()` `@Bean` we can do the same for the `DelayHandler`:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "delayInput")
public MessageHandler delayMessageHandler() {
    DelayHandler delayHandler = new DelayHandler("myGroup");
    ...
    return delayHandler;
}
```

NOTE: The latest documentation for version `5.0` will contain a sample how to configure `delayer` via Annotations and Java DSL.

Comment: i could not find in latest documentation for version 5.0, sample how to configure delayer via Annotations and Java DSL

Comment: Agreed. There is just no one. Please, raise a JIRA on the matter. We fix docs for Java configuration on demand. Thanks

Comment: It's [already there](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#delayer-namespace) and has been since [March](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/c85b9cbb20d9973198ccfcc0ca397ad452ced784#diff-3af5f94f013253ce5b7f891dbef27fa9).